Can the Mesh Deform modifier do something that the Surface Deform Modifier can't?
While the mesh deform modifier seems to give slightly better deformations, I can't find a situation where I wouldn't just use the surface deform. Can somebody enlighten me please?

The main difference is that Mesh deform works with any arbitrary mesh, like a lattice modifier with a 3D cube, but you're not restricted to cubes.
Mesh Deform Modifier:

Surface deform is optimized for 2D meshes, like planes, usually meant for cloth simulations.
You can see how using a surface deform modifier with the 3D mesh kind of breaks down.

But use it with a 2D mesh and it works great.


that makes sense, thank you !
